# Velocity JS Hangs on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-animate, velocity.js

I am hitting an obscure issue while testing on the iPad.  I have a series of elements that shoot out onto the page into their respective locations.  However, recently on the iPad4 I have found that the elements do not shoot to their positions.  The elements have the "velocity-animating" class applied but then they hang and never animate.  I have tried using stop() as well as clearQueue() but with no luck.

```
scene.find(".hotspot").each(function() {
        $(this).velocity({
            top: obj[name][i]['top'],
            left: obj[name][i]['left'],
            opacity: 1
        }, 250);
        i++
    });
```

There are several variables used there, but an array of elements is passed into the function and I iterate through it animating to the element's set top and left values.

Oddly though, if I rotate the iPad from landscape to portrait and back, the elements are in their correct spots.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody who may stumble upon this, the issue was the recent inclusion of an animated gif underneath the elements that were to be animated.  It seems as though there was too much animating going on at once and the iPad would simply hang up.  I resolved this by animating the required elements then once those were done, running a setTimeout to fade in the animated gif underneath.

Not ideal but it works.